# "She was not happy." - Ambiguity of the 'to be' in English

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

I always think about this since in my language (Portuguese) the verb 'to be' has two meanings for which I will give two examples:

"She was in the room." - here the verb to be has the meaning of 'estar'.

and

"She was not a customer." - here it means 'ser'.

> Take  "She was not happy"
>
> "Ela não estava feliz" - she was not happy at the moment.
>
> "Ela não era feliz" - she was not a happy person

The question is: Is there a way to distinguish the meanings of 'was' in the example or do I have to go with "She was not a happy person".

Comment: I can't answer your question in general (how to map instances of "be" onto *ser* and *estar*), but if Portugese follows conventions similar to Spanish, and if I'm remembering the Spanish conventions correctly, one gross division is along the line of inherent vs conditional states. Since "being unhappy" is typically an ephemeral, passing condition, I suspect that in the particular case of "She was not happy", the *was* corresponds to an *estar*. By contrast, if English speaker said "She is an unhappy person", that describes an inherent characteristic,  so the *is* probably corresponds to *ser*.

Comment: I actually do not understand your question, and I am fluent in Spanish and conversant with Portuguese. What are you trying to learn?

Comment: My take is he's trying to figure out when an English copula would be translated as "ser" vs "estar".

Comment: @DanBron But that is not an English question.

Comment: Nope, it's not. Unless there exists in English syntax the concept of a conditional copula? (I'm no grammarian, as you've likely guessed by now.)

Comment: “He’s sick” => *estar*, but “He’s a sickly fellow” => *ser*.

Comment: I gather the OP wants to know if there is a way to distinguish between "a permanent condition" from a "temporary condition" when verb to be is used.  There are instances when (out of a context) a sentence might be ambiguous.

Comment: @Luis But this just doesn’t make much sense. It doesn’t require translation between languages to find that there is not a 1:1 mapping of words to meaning. This happens in just one language. Yes, I could teach pointers about how to know how it works with Spanish and Portuguese, but this is not the place for it — at all.

Comment: @tchrist it is about English

Comment: @SurvMach No, it is not. If it were about English, nobody would care about this difference without a distinction. We in English are perfectly content to allow the polysemic superposition to flourish without any need to collapse the probabilities into concrete, limited meaning. Just because you in Portuguese are not comfortable with that does not make this an English problem. It is a Portuguese problem — and translation is offtopic,

Comment: @SurvMach, I sympathize with you, but it's not about English as "about" is defined by the charter of this site (we discuss English in-and-of itself, not how it relates to other languages; just as the question "In Korea, we take our shoes off before we enter the house, please explain why you do not do this in America" isn't about *America*, per se.)

Comment: @tchrist What he wants to know is how to distinguish a temporary condition from a permanent condition when verb to be is used, and there is no context and no clues.  My guess is that you can't.   For instance: "He is cold".  (he is a cold person? or he needs a warm coat ?)

Comment: @DanBron You got it, have it taken down.

Comment: Removing the question would be unfair to @medica's upvoted answer, which manages to answer in an on-topic way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do not have the two *to be* verbs found in Spanish and some other Romance languages). Just the one, which covers the meanings of both *ser* and *estar*.

I *am* American and I *am* happy both use the same verb.

With *She was not happy*, there is not enough context to actually know if she was not a happy person or if she wasn't happy at the moment; but you will not find that in the verb. It would be given by an adverb or another word:

She was momentarily unhappy. She was an unhappy person.

Answer (score -2):

In English, for the momentary condition you would say:

> She was not happy.

For the continual condition you would say something like:

> She is not ever happy.
>
> She has not ever been happy.